# Finding values of limits

Tags: limits

What are the methods required to find the value of the limit approaching 9 for (x-9)/(x^(1/2) - 3)

I tried multiplying the fraction with its conjugate but I ended up with no infinity. How do I solve this ?

Comment: The polynomial identity $y^2-a^2=(y+a)(y-a)$.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is  near $9$, so it is positive and

$$ x-9=(\sqrt{x}+3)(\sqrt{x}-3)$$

thus the function becomes after simplification,

$$\sqrt{x}+3$$ and the limit is

$$\sqrt{9}+3=6$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$(x-9)=(\sqrt{x})^2-(3)^2=(\sqrt{x}-3)(\sqrt{x}+3)$$